# How to scale k8s pods according to rabbitmq queue message rate?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

My application is running as a container on top of `kubernetes`.
The application consume messages from `rabbitmq`.

I can't predict the exact amount of `cpu` so I don't want to use it as autoscale limit, though I did set the `prefetch` to something that looks normal.
Is there a way to follow the number of messages in the queue,
and once there are too much to tell `k8s` to autoscale?
Or maybe set the autoscale to follow message rate?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find much content on this which didn't involve using an external source such as StackDriver.

I spent several days working through all the issues, and wrote up a demo app with code on how to do it.  I hope it will help someone:

https://ryanbaker.io/2019-10-07-scaling-rabbitmq-on-k8s/

Answer (score 1):

You could either use Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with custom metrics, which need to be provided by some custom metrics API server (boilerplate: https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/custom-metrics-apiserver).

Or use a custom autoscaler (probably outdated: https://github.com/onfido/k8s-rabbit-pod-autoscaler).

So you either provide the metrics to HPA or you run some application that has the metrics and sends scaling requirements to the kubernetes API.

Comment: The autoscaler you mentioned is not actually an autoscaler, it is just an application (deployment) that scales the app... How do I build and load the API server you mentioned first?

Comment: fast forward, i'm using keda now for scaling pods on queue metrics, here's the doc for rabbitmq https://keda.sh/docs/2.2/scalers/rabbitmq-queue/

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://itnext.io/kubernetes-workers-autoscaling-based-on-rabbitmq-queue-size-cb0803193cdf) looks like ready answer to your question. It describes how to set up **Horizontal Pod Autoscaler** based on **RabbitMQ** queue size.